# Splash screen loader animation is not animating

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using an `XML` drawable as splash screen which is a `layer-list` element. Inside it, I am using an `animation.xml` file, which contains a loading animation.

While showing the splash screen, I can see the loading animation drawable, but without any animation. I am probably doing something wrong.

Can anyone please point me out the correct way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/purple_700" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <item
        android:width="300dp"
        android:height="300dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/loading_animation"
        android:gravity="bottom" />
</layer-list>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the last `item` with this:

```
<item
    android:width="300dp"
    android:height="300dp">

    <animated-rotate
        android:drawable="@drawable/loading_image"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />

</item>
```

Comment: Thanks! That really is not the case, and I can see the first frame of the animation. It is just not moving! However, tested it as you said - no result! It gets hidden if I move up.